# How do I convert a mySQL DATETIME type to a string for use in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

I want to display a DATETIME I get from a mySQL database as a String in Javascript.

I'm using PHP to put the DATETIME into a variable: $mydatetime.

It displays fine on the PHP page, but not in my javascript function.

```
<?php
    echo $mydatetime       --> 2010-04-19 13:00:00
    echo "<script language=javascript>myfunction($mydatetime);</script>";        
?>
```

Javascript

```
function myfunction(mydatetime) {
    alert(mydatetime);
}
```

This produces an error in my console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number**

I've tried many things to try to convert mydatetime to a string, but nothing seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what format you need for your function - you don't specify.
Chances are you just need to enclose the value in quotes:

```
echo "<script language=javascript>myfunction('$mydatetime');</script>";
```

But the general way to convert dates from mySQL to something else in PHP is:

1. Turn the date into a timestamp: `$mytimestamp = strtotime($mydatetime);` Strtotime can read a great number of time formats, DATETIME is among them. Manual on strtotime [**here**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
2. Output the timestamp in any format you like: `echo date("Y-m-d", $mytimestamp);` Manual on `date` formatting options [**here**](http://www.php.net/date)

Answer (score 0):

It's a string, so Javascript needs it in quotes:

```
<?php
    echo $mydatetime       --> 2010-04-19 13:00:00
    echo "<script language=javascript>myfunction('$mydatetime');</script>";        
?>
```